# How do I write the XSLT to extract the XML data (mainly from attributes) that's structured as a different tree every time?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am a XSLT newbie. I am trying to develop XSLT to transform XML data into HTML as per code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:key name="Name" match="Item" use="@Name"/>
    <xsl:template match="item">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Course Profile</h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Item">
                <xsl:if test="string-length(@Name) &gt; 0 ">
                    <span>Name: </span>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
                    &#160;
                 </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(@Title) &gt; 0 ">
                    <span>Title: </span>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
                        &#160;
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(@Description) &gt; 0 and @Description!=@Title">
                    <span>Description: </span>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
                     &#160;
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(@Value) &gt; 0 ">
                    <span>Value: </span>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
                    &#160;
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(Name) &gt; 0  ">
                    <span>Actual value: </span>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                    &#160;
                </xsl:if>
                <br/>
                <hr/>
            </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Into XHTML with data (not the looks! - I do not want to use XSL-FO) from XML data that like this (that's my problem - it's not always the same xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StructureData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Object ID="cacms^977" StructureLevel="5" Title="test programme">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="author" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-05-28-07.02.09"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="title" Value="test programme"/>
            <Item Name="description" Value="revalidation"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="UAT testing content"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata>
            <Item Index="1" Name="Programme Type" Value="Appip"/>
            <Item Index="2" Name="Course Type" Value="Adult learning &gt;20"/>
            <Item Index="2" Name="Course Code" Value="xxTT2"/>
            <Item Index="1" Name="Status" Value="01-In development"/>
            <Item Index="1" Name="Metadata Schema" Value="LOM 1.0"/>
            <Item Index="1" Name="Minimum Version" Value="IE 7.0"/>
            <Item Index="1" Name="Maximum Version" Value="IE 8.0"/>
            <Item Index="17" Name="Awarding Body" Value="TT"/>
            <Item Index="1" Name="NQ Award Type" Value="Major Award"/>
            <Item Index="6" Name="NQ Award Level" Value="Level 06"/>
            <Item Index="6" Name="Award Title" Value="none"/>
        </CustomMetadata>
    </Object>
    <Object ID="cacms^978" StructureLevel="4" Title="test phase">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="author" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-05-28-07.02.10"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="title" Value="test phase"/>
            <Item Name="description" Value="revalidation"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="UAT testing content"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata/>
    </Object>
    <Object ID="cacms^979" StructureLevel="3" Title="test module">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="author" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-05-28-07.02.10"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="title" Value="test module"/>
            <Item Name="description" Value="revalidation"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="UAT testing content"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata>
            <Item Index="1" Name="NQ Award Type" Value="Major Award"/>
            <Item Index="6" Name="NQ Award Level" Value="Level 06"/>
            <Item Index="6" Name="Expiry/Review Date" Value="2012-05-09"/>
            <Item Index="10" Name="Typical Learning Time (Duration hours)" Value=""/>
            <Item Index="10" Name="Award Title" Value="non"/>
            <Item Index="17" Name="Awarding Body" Value="T"/>
        </CustomMetadata>
    </Object>
    <Object ID="cacms^980" StructureLevel="2" Title="test unit">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="author" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-08-22-10.21.17"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="title" Value="May 9 test unit - Sunny"/>
            <Item Name=" description" Value="revalidation"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="UAT testing content"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata/>
    </Object>
    <Object ID="cacms^1001" StructureLevel="1" Title="test cluster ">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="author" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-08-22-10.15.37"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="title" Value="test cluster"/>
            <Item Name="description" Value="delete"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="UAT testing content"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata>
            <Item Name="Phase" Value="NCDB"/>
        </CustomMetadata>
    </Object>
    <Object ID="cacms^1053" StructureLevel="0" Title="test ">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="UAT testing content"/>
            <Item Name="sound" Value=""/>
            <Item Name="author" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-05-28-07.02.11"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata/>
    </Object>
    <Object ID="cacms^1054" StructureLevel="0" Title="reverificaton use of templated - Sunny">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="UAT testing content"/>
            <Item Name="sound" Value=""/>
            <Item Name="author" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-05-28-07.02.11"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata/>
        <ObjectData>
            <Item Description="Advanced Table Title Bar Cover Page" ID="cacms^2879" Title="reverification Template Cover page QA 39/01 Training Plan Title Bar" Type="Advanced Table">
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p>&#160;</p><p>CACMS Re-verificiation text <em>Version X.Y Month Year italics</em></p><p>&#160;</p>]]></col>
                </row>
            </Item>
        </ObjectData>
    </Object>
    <Object ID="cacms^1055" StructureLevel="0" Title="May 14 test page 1 doc mode">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="UAT testing content"/>
            <Item Name="sound" Value=""/>
            <Item Name="author" Value=""/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-05-28-07.02.11"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata/>
        <ObjectData>
            <Item Description="Advanced Table Title Bar Cover Page" ID="cacms^2866" Title="May 9 test page 1 non doc mode_1 - Title Bar" Type="Advanced Table">
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p>&#160;</p><p>Domestic Appliance Servicing <em>Version 4.6 September 2011</em></p><p>&#160;</p>]]></col>
                </row>
            </Item>
            <Item Description="QA39/01 Training Plan Title Block" ID="cacms^2867" Title="QA39/01 Training Plan Title Block" Type="Advanced Table">
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p><em></em>&#160;</p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>TT - TT</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p><em>TRAINING PLAN</em></p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p><em>DESIGNED TO STANDARD NO. QA39/01</em></p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
            </Item>
            <Item Description="Domestic Appliance Servicing  QA39/01" ID="cacms^2869" Title="May 9 test page 1 non doc mode_35 -  Domestic Appliance Servicing MANCO QA39/01" Type="Advanced Table">
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<strong>GLM CODE</strong>]]></col>
                    <col><![CDATA[<strong>MANCO CODES</strong> ]]></col>
                    <col/>
                    <col/>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<strong>XX028</strong>]]></col>
                    <col><![CDATA[<strong>76170</strong>]]></col>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
            </Item>
            <Item Description="Advanced Table QA39 Status Block" ID="cacms^2870" Title="May 9 test page 1 non doc mode_73 - QA39 Status Block" Type="Advanced Table">
                <row>
                    <col>STATUS</col>
                    <col/>
                    <col/>
                    <col/>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>PROPOSAL DATE</col>
                    <col>TT INTERNAL APPROVAL DATE</col>
                    <col>AWARD COUNCIL VALIDATION DATE</col>
                    <col>REVIEW BY DATE</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>AUGUST 1995</col>
                    <col>JUNE 2010</col>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                    <col>JUNE 2005</col>
                </row>
            </Item>
            <Item Description="TT logo with no Tagline at 300 dpi" ID="cacms^TT99" Title="TT Logo no Tagline 300 dpi" Type="Graphic"/>
            <Item Description="Text" ID="cacms^2871" Title="test page 1 non doc mode_107 - Funded statement" Type="Text">       Funded financed   </Item>
            <Item Description="Programme Title Block QA39/01" ID="cacms^2874" Title="May 14 test page 1 doc mode_14 - Programme Title Block" Type="Advanced Table">
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<strong><em>TRAINING TITLE</em></strong>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p><strong>&#160;Domestic Appliance Servicing</strong></p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<em>&#160;&#160; Version 4.6 September 2011</em>]]></col>
                </row>
            </Item>
        </ObjectData>
    </Object>
    <Object ID="cacms^981" StructureLevel="1" Title="test cluster">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="author" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-05-28-07.02.10"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="title" Value="test cluster"/>
            <Item Name="description" Value="test"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="UAT testing content"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata>
            <Item Name="Phase" Value="re-verification"/>
        </CustomMetadata>
    </Object>
    <Object ID="cacms^1047" StructureLevel="0" Title="QA39 Test Type codes template - Sunny">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="Adult Training Templates"/>
            <Item Name="sound" Value=""/>
            <Item Name="author" Value=""/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-05-28-07.02.11"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata/>
        <ObjectData>
            <Item Description="Key to Test Type Codes" ID="cacms^2881" Title="Training Plan - table of codes" Type="Advanced Table">
                <row isHeader="true">
                    <col><![CDATA[<p>&#160;</p><p>TRAINING PLAN</p><p>&#160;</p>]]></col>
                    <col/>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>KEY TO TEST TYPE CODES </col>
                    <col/>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Assignment</col>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p>A</p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Course Work</col>
                    <col>CW</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Drawing</col>
                    <col>D</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Essay (Written)</col>
                    <col>E</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Integrated Assessment</col>
                    <col>IA</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Multiple Choice</col>
                    <col>MC</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Not Applicable</col>
                    <col>NA</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Oral</col>
                    <col>O</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Practical</col>
                    <col>P</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Profiling</col>
                    <col>PF</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Project</col>
                    <col>PR</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Short Answer</col>
                    <col>SA</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Workplace Observation</col>
                    <col>WO</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>Written</col>
                    <col>W</col>
                </row>
            </Item>
        </ObjectData>
    </Object>
    <Object ID="cacms^1048" StructureLevel="0" Title=" non-doc mode page">
        <CoreMetadata>
            <Item Name="version" Value="1"/>
            <Item Name="language" Value="English"/>
            <Item Name="subject" Value="UAT testing content"/>
            <Item Name="sound" Value=""/>
            <Item Name="author" Value=""/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_time" Value="2012-05-28-07.39.04"/>
            <Item Name="last_updated_by" Value="rien"/>
            <Item Name="expiry_date" Value=""/>
        </CoreMetadata>
        <CustomMetadata/>
        <ObjectData>
            <Item Description="QA39/01 Training Plan Title Block" ID="cacms^2867" Title="QA39/01 Training Plan Title Block" Type="Advanced Table">
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p><em></em>&#160;</p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>TT - TT</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p><em>TRAINING PLAN</em></p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p><em>DESIGNED TO STANDARD NO. QA39/01</em></p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
            </Item>
            <Item Description="Programme Title Block QA39/01" ID="cacms^2868" Title="test page 1 non doc mode_14 - Programme Title Block" Type="Advanced Table">
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p>&#160;</p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>TRAINING TITLE</col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p><strong>&#160;Domestic Appliance Servicing</strong></p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<em>&#160;&#160;Version 4.6 September 2011</em>]]></col>
                </row>
            </Item>
            <Item Description="Copyright Page - Advanced Table QA39" ID="cacms^2880" Title="Copyright Page - QA 39/01 copyright text" Type="Advanced Table">
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<p>&#160;</p><p>Published by: </p><p>TTT, </p><p>P.O. Box 1, </p><p>TTTT Street, </p><p>TT, TT</p><p>&#169; TT 2011<br /></p>]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[The copyright of this document is the property of TT except where copyright is acknowledged to belong to a third party.]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[&#160;]]></col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col>All rights reserved. </col>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col><![CDATA[<b><font size="2" face="Arial-BoldMT"><font size="2" face="Arial-BoldMT"><p align="left">&#160;</p></font></font></b>]]></col>
                </row>
            </Item>
        </ObjectData>
    </Object>
</StructureData>
```

**How do I write the XSLT to extract the XML data (mainly from attributes) that's structured as a different tree every time?**

Comment: XML file is different every time it is sent to me. How do write the XSLT to extract the same data when the nodes are structured differently every time?

Comment: Why am I getting negative points?

Answer (score 0):

you simply have to write an xslt for each type in your xsd ruleset docs and apply the sufficient to instances